# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') & React Props Rules

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Summary of the Problem**

- Consider a search bar `<SearchBar/>` (where you type different college majors) and a dropdown `<Dropdown/>` (a dropdown showing some details about a major i.e. "About Computer Science > Professors of Computer Science", "Computer Science Ratings > Best Computer Science Calsses", etc). I enter a word into the search bar, then I click submit. The information on the dropdown should change depending on what the user submits. The information that goes in the dropdown is fetched from a mongo collection
- Inside a React component, I have the following [function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTrGA.png). This function is called when the user clicks *submit*.
- I expect the `major` variable to be updated once the above function is called (i.e. when the user clicks submit)
- The dropdown is returned as `<Dropdown dropdown_information={major.informationPiece1}/>`, where `major.informationPieces1` is a list of objects
- The `Dropdown` component definition looks like:

```
const Dropdown = ({informationPieces1}) => {


  return (
    <>
        <ul>
            {informationPiece1.map((piece, index) => {
                
                return (
                   <h1 key={index}> {piece.name} <h1/>
                )
            })}
            
        </ul>
    </>
  )
}
```

- However, it seems that `informationPiece1` in `informationPiece1.map((piece, index) => ...`  comes up as undefined. I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`
- However, if I `console.log(informationPieces1)` inside the `Dropdown` React component defintion, I see the array in the console properly.

**I believe this is a React problem. I believe this may be related to an incorrect use of React's props on my part. What steps would you recommend me to follow to verify if this is true?**

Answer (score 0):

You are calling Dropdown component with `dropdown_information` as prop and expecting `informationPieces1` in the component. So or you call the component with the prop `informationPieces1` or you use the prop `dropdown_information` inside the component

I'll clarify:

```js
const Dropdown = ({informationPieces1}) => { // if you define the component like this the you must call it:

<Dropdown informationPieces1={}/>


///////////////////////////

// If you call the component like this:
<Dropdown dropdown_information={}/>

//then you must write the definition as:
const Dropdown = ({dropdown_information}) => {
```

Your prop's names must match in both the definition and the call